# Is it Okay for mysql to hit 59% without no query running in my site?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb

Please I need some little help from you guys.

I have a VPS I bought since 2018 and since then one of the most difficult thing i have been facing is high load on my SQL, but i guess that was due to my big database of 1GB size.
my vps spec is 16GB RAM & 6 cores.

Recently I have sold the site and deleted the 1GB database which was causing me issues on mysql server. Ever since then I have little wp sites on the server with No much traffic, but I still have mysql hitting up to 59% sometimes. I have check to see if its long query that is taking it but nothing at all.

One day I even switch off my apeche just to make sure I see the sql server uses low cpu process but to my greatest surprise I am getting at least 5-15%

I thought since no apache is connected the sql server has to fall to 0.2 or i don't even want to see it among my list of processes when i run `top` command.

Please Guru in the house is it okay to get this limit while no website is running on the server. and what are the optimization needed to stop it from reaching such percentage even with no long query running on the websites. or is there an evil spirit from the old 1gb deleted database that is still disturbing the mysql server. help me out please.

Comment: Connect to MySQL as 'root' and do `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`  High CPU or "Load" implies poorly indexes and/or written query -- find it, then let's discuss.

Comment: here is what i get as from show processlist:[HERE](https://pastebin.com/raw/1jyUeYrK)

Comment: If this is WordPress, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: i dont know more about database sql but do i have to drop the wp_postmeta table before creating another one based on the solution you specified on the link? and wont i lose my files if i drop them?

Comment: Dropping wp_postmeta will lose important data; don't do it!.  See `ALTER TABLE`.  I don't think you showed enough of the General log to provide clues.  (Except that WP is involved.)

Comment: the general log is too long check it out [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/rsRwPb8e). then for the  `CREATE TABLE` do I have to replace the `ALTER TABLE` ?

Comment: You probably should not embark on any fixes until you have some more experience with MySQL.  Meanwhile, I see that WP is sloppier with its code than I realized.  90% of the stuff in that listing is sloppily written, inefficient, redundant, etc.  WP needs advice; then you can benefit from it.

Comment: please you wouldnt sit back and watch me suffer this way, I need some guild to go through this to fix this, i really know it can work

Comment: Sorry, I thought the ALTER was there.  It wasn't, so I uploaded it.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta .  Caveat:  I have not tested it.

Comment: i just need special guide on how to achieve this.

Comment: Learn to use the "mysql commandline tool".  Or phpmyadmin.  Or MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Please edit and update your question rather than answering in comments.

Comment: @Rick James i can use phpmyadmin very well.

Answer (score 0):

With nothing running, mysqld will use 0% of CPU, therefore you must have something running. Enable general log, that will show you exactly what it's doing.

And 1GB isn't a particularly big database.

Comment: I already have `log-error` automatically server by the hosting provider. or is there any other log i should set?

Comment: You need general_log.

Comment: Alright u will create one now and give feed back in some hours time

Comment: here is what I am seeing after enabling general log [HERE](https://pastebin.com/raw/CNhB3Efa)

Comment: I guess that disproves your hypothesis that the server isn't doing anything when it is using up 59% of CPU.

Comment: When the server is not doing anything it reads to between 1-15%... But if I turn on my apache the highest it can go is 59% without any Hugh query running on the server.

Comment: So tail -f the general log under both conditions, and you'll see the queries the server is processing. Then you'll have to figure out what process is issuing those queries.

Comment: no much difference from what is on the general log the only thing i saw newly there is this 

`24830 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on
                 24830 Query    select version()
                 24830 Quit
200518 20:32:55  24831 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on mysql
                 24831 Query    set sql_mode='' /* DISABLE ANSI_QUOTES and normalize */
                 24831 Query    SELECT user FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE 'cpses\_%'
              `

Comment: @XATA Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE my_options; ?  Thanks

Comment: @Wilson Hauck here is the show create table you requested for [HERE](https://pastebin.com/raw/wvTYx6sk)

Comment: @XATA Please post TEXT results of this query -  # selmmaMLdisc-my-options.sql    min max avg MaxLength  2020-05-22 WLH mysqlservertuning.com
# email info@mysqlservertuning.com   sharable comments, please 
SELECT 
    MIN(option_id), MAX(option_id), AVG(option_id), MAX(LENGTH(option_id)), 
    MIN(option_name), MAX(option_name), AVG(option_name), MAX(LENGTH(option_name)), 
    MIN(option_value), MAX(option_value), AVG(option_value), MAX(LENGTH(option_value)), 
    MIN(autoload), MAX(autoload), AVG(autoload), MAX(LENGTH(autoload)) 
        FROM my_options;